# Insert if in a function in R to run different tests inside based on result of a p-value

Tags: r, function, if-statement

Let's start with this dataframe:

```
fish <- structure(list(`p-value` = c(0.0428191105308652, 0.00283156203306167, 
0.478572038814442, 0.55135017792096, 0.272415971693948, 0.0152562656081705
), Test_Diff = c("Welch", "Welch", "t test", "t test", "t test", 
"Welch")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("tito_3", "pasiega_88", 
"covaciella_25", "covaciella_26", "niaux_54", "niaux_130"))
```

The dataframe, shown next, indicates de p-value for the homogeneity of variances by using the Fisher test in each row (`p-value`). The `Test_Diff` column indicates which test to run in order to test their differences (based on the p-value).

```
                  p-value Test_Diff
tito_3        0.042819111     Welch
pasiega_88    0.002831562     Welch
covaciella_25 0.478572039    t test
covaciella_26 0.551350178    t test
niaux_54      0.272415972    t test
niaux_130     0.015256266     Welch
```

I created two functions to run the t test and the Welch test.

```
test_ttest <- function(data) {
  gat <- gather(data, key = "Dating")
  bison_ttest <- t.test(value~Dating, data = gat, var.equal = TRUE)
  bison_ttest
}

test_welch <- function(data) {
  gat <- gather(data, key = "Dating")
  bison_ttest <- t.test(value~Dating, data = gat, var.equal = F)
  bison_ttest
}
```

Therefore, I can run:

- `test_ttest(covaciella_25)`
- `test_welch(tito_3)`
- etc

However, I would like to automatize this process. Because the p-values in the dataframe `fish` dynamically change, each row can change from t test to Welch.

Ultimately, I would like to develop 1 function with `if` and `if_else`, to accommodate my situation. I would name it `t_or_welch()`.

- If I input `t_or_welch(tito_3)`, because the original dataset `tito_3` has the same row name as in `fish` row 1, it should be able to identify it requires a Welch test.

Comment: It's not an answer to what you're trying to do, but Welch's t-test has equal power if the variances *are* equal so it's almost always fine to use Welch for all of these (I believe this is why R defaults to var.equal=FALSE)

Comment: You should provide reproducible data. The results of the var.test are not enough. If you use a construction such as `var.test(x, y)$p.value < .05` you will get a return of `TRUE` or `FALSE` which you can use directly with `t.test()`.